# How to pass dynamic data as Body Data in JMeter while doing performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

Can you help me to pass **dynamic data** as **body data** for the below sampler.

{"dealer_code":"**30274**","version":"**566**","preview_date":"","exterior_color":{"name":"Energetic Orange Metallic","prcode":"F14 4M4M","mrdp":0,"price":"600"},"car_configurator_model_code":"**C113KZ-GPJAPJA-GPLAPLA-GWZBWZB-GW05W05**","model_year":"**2023**","sfid":"**01t9q000000FRoGAAW**","sub_brand":"**PV**","model_code":"**C113KZ/23**"}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xcjv.png)

I tried to pass the details as parameter but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute hard-coded values with the appropriate [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly in the "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

```
{
  "dealer_code": "30274",
  "version": "566",
  "preview_date": "",
  "exterior_color": {
    "name": "Energetic Orange Metallic",
    "prcode": "F14 4M4M",
    "mrdp": 0,
    "price": "600"
  },
  "car_configurator_model_code": "${configuratorModelCode}",
  "model_year": "${modelYear}",
  "sfid": "01t9q000000FRoGAAW",
  "sub_brand": "${subBrand}",
  "model_code": "${modelCode}"
}
```

[image]

The variables values should either be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) (i.e. using data from the previous response) or parameterized using external data source (i.e. using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG))